# How to minify CSS and JavaScript files in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: web-applications, minify, bundling-and-minification

I am building a web application for mobile using visual studio, and I wanted to know how do I minify all my CSS files into one file, and also all my JavaScript to one minified file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the Visual Studio 2015 Bundler & Minifier,extention https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40 this used to be apart of Web Essentials in previous versions of Visual Studio, but was separated, into it's own extension.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this extension? I've been trying (and getting very frustrated with) the syntax for the bundleconfig-schema.json. I find it hard to believe that I have to add each javascript file manually to this file, but that's what it looks like.

Comment: @Jonathan Had the same question.  Looks like it does support globbing patterns https://github.com/madskristensen/bundlerMinifier#bundleconfigjson #greatsuccess

Comment: There was a time I would have recommended this extension (VS2013) - but the 2015 is hot mess.   It's prone to crashing VS if the LESS/JS files are too large, and the bundle/compile configs get confused (not to mention with his updates, out of sync) - where it doesn't minify like it should anymore - and removes options to do so (right now i have a JS I can't minify for whatever reason).

This extension needs serious work before it's production ready.

Comment: Have had nothing but trouble trying to use this extension, crashing VS continually.

Answer (score 7):

The below link explains a lot better 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/08/15/adding-web-optimization-to-a-web-pages-site.aspx

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 1):

It's handled in the bundleconfig.json for asp.net mvc core

Here is full article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Answer (score 1):

Both extensions mentioned in other answers seem abandoned, but the good thing, Visual Studio has built-on support for `npm` and Grunt/Gulp tasks - that can "watch" a file, and minify/compile JS, CSS, SASS and everything else you have in your project.

1. Drop a `package.json` into your project root folder, with Grunt or Gulp added there. Visual Studio will "detect" it and install all the `npm` packages in the background.
2. Add `Gruntfile.js` (or Gulpfile if you prefer Gulp) and Visual Studio "task runner" will also detect it automatically.
3. Edit Gruntfile (or Gulpfile) to minify/compile your files (tons of info can be found online) and optinally add a "watcher" too.
4. Under "View - Other Windows - Task Runner" configure these tasks to run on project open.

I wrote a detailed [blog post](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/294-building-and-minifying-js-css-less-sass-in-visual-studio-with-no-extensions/) with screenshots and everything, since it can be overwhelming for VS/.NET people to get familiar with `npm/grunt/gulp/npm-scripts` at first, but it's easy, trust me! I've been there myself.